# It is possible to implement AMP in a single application?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, amp-html

I have read the AMP documentation but, still bit confused. Already have a React app running, it's possible to implement AMP in the same application? or do i need to create another app just for AMP?

Also tried using [optimizer-express](https://github.com/ampproject/amp-toolbox/tree/master/packages/optimizer-express) as middleware and had no success.

Does anyone have/had a similar situation?

Comment: It's possible, the AMP pages need to be server-side-rendered with React though. Next.js supports this out-of-the-box: https://nextjs.org/blog/next-8-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it not possible to implement AMP in a single application. A SPA must render page in client side with javascript but AMP page haven't custom javascript (unlimited js) and can't add SPA router like `react-router`. AMP sites usually serve in the server or serve in a static server. So you can not implement a full SPA AMP app although you can implement some dynamic functionality in AMP with [amp-bind component](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-bind) and [amp-script component](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/?format=websites)